# How to umount a busy windows file using Ubuntu in WSL?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, umount

I must unmount *drvfs* and remount it with the ‘metadata’ flag to use a new file system features to WSL that allows making changes in permissions in WSL.
But when I do this:

`sudo umount /mnt/c`

It returns

`umount: /mnt/c: target is busy`

How can I force the process to stop without lose data?
Which process could be running that should not?

Comment: How about mounting the drives with metadata automatically without doing a umount/mount cycle? See this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/). Mounting option can be added in `/etc/wsl.conf` file.

Answer (score 8):

Try `umount -l /mnt/c`.
According to the man page it does the following

> ```
>    -l, --lazy
>           Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.
> ```